# Can appengine send email from external SMTP server?

Tags: google-app-engine, smtp

Our customers want to send emails from our java appengine application using their email accounts, with their smtp servers. Is that possible? Verifying all their email addresses in appengine is NOT an option. Would it be possible to send email from an appengine application using an external SMTP server?

Thank you very much.

Comment: hope this help https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/SJDCT9NRLVQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way for an App Engine app to make a connection to an external SMTP server. If you want to do this, you'll need to find or build a webservice that sends email via an HTTP-based interface.

Comment: Will it be possible with: App Engine Sockets Trusted Tester Program?

Comment: @voscausa Unlikely, because allowing outgoing connections on port 25 would be ripe for abuse.

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly to do today, but requires some indirection. If they set up a web form (cgi script, web app , whatever) that forwards to their SMTP server (after making the appropriate authentication checks, of course), then it's a simple matter for an App Engine app to make a POST.